# Uploading File to server taking Long Time Android

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I have developed application where I am sending audio file and receiver information to server, Its working but many times uploading takes very long time and cause ConnectionTimeout exception.

Code I am using now:

```
BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 120000);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
postStr = new Gson().toJson(audioBean);
File file = new File(audioBean.getFilePath());
ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(file, "audio/wav");
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
mpEntity.addPart("audio", new StringBody(postStr));
mpEntity.addPart("file", contentBody);
httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

above code runs in thread, please tell me how to improve performance

Comment: What's the size of the file, how long does it take? How do you connect to the server (WLAN, mobile data)?

Comment: Size is below 2mb, it takes 30sec but some times it reaches Timeout, I am using Wifi for net access